Layer disappear after projection in R
I'm trying to calculate the standard deviation across 12 layers and then reproject the result to another CRS. Everything seems to be working fine until the conversion, where the layer disappears. Previously, I've done similar conversions without calculating the standard deviation layer and everything seems fine.
library(raster)
library(terra)

# calculate standard deviation 
temp_list <- vector(mode = "list", length = 12)

for (i in 1:12) {
    month <- sprintf("%02d", i)
    temp_list[[i]] <- raster(rast(paste0("climate/wc2.1_5m_tavg/wc2.1_5m_tavg_", month, ".tif")))
}

temp_sd <- calc(stack(temp_list), fun = sd)
temp_sd_SpatRas <- as(temp_sd, "SpatRaster")

# convert to other CRS
envRasterESRI54017 <- project(temp_sd_SpatRas, "ESRI:54017")

# check layer values
tibble::as_tibble(temp_sd_SpatRas)
#> # A tibble: 3,170,214 × 1
#>    layer
#>    <dbl>
#>  1  0   
#>  2  0   
#>  3  0   
#>  4  0   
#>  5  0   
#>  6  8.79
#>  7 11.8 
#>  8 11.8 
#>  9 11.8 
#> 10 11.8 
#> # ℹ 3,170,204 more rows

However, when attempting to view the layer of the raster after converting to ESRI:54017, nothing appears:
tibble::as_tibble(envRasterESRI54017)
#> A tibble: 0 × 1
#> ℹ 1 variable: layer <dbl>
#> Warning:
#> [readValues] raster has no values  

How can I identify what I've done wrong? Additionally, how can I achieve my goal in R?

Can you show us what happens with the normal print method on your rasters and not as_tibble which is pretty useless here. It doesn't show the coordinate info.

Problem solved when following @Jeffery solutions :)

Super, although it doesn't explain where your code stopped working, so the mystery remains!

You are doing a lot of unnecessary back and forth between raster and terra. The terra package is the modern analog, replacing raster so, I would recommend conducting your entire workflow there. I have found that having both packages active in the same global environment can cause issues. If you are going to add raster (via library or require) then invoke the package environment when calling a function that exists in both packages (eg., project). A function can be directly called from its package environment using double colons (eg., terra::rast). It may also help coercing the EPSG into a projection string that terra can directly read. The preferred method, when reprojecting raster data in terra, is to create an empty raster in the new projection space (as shown).
Read rasters and calculate standard deviation
library(terra)
f <- paste0("climate/wc2.1_5m_tavg/wc2.1_5m_tavg_", 1:12, ".tif")
  r <- rast(f)
    rsd <- terra::stdev(r)

Project the current rasters extent, create a reference raster in the new projection space and reproject the standard deviation raster. Please note that, it the original data is not projected (ie., lat/long), you will have to define a resolution rather than pulling it from the original raster. The same would be the case if you are switching projection units say, going from meters to feet (most projections are in meters but ones like Stateplane are in feet).
e <- terra::project(ext(r), crs(r), crs("ESRI:54017"))
  ref <- rast(e, resolution = res(r), crs= crs("ESRI:54017"))
    rsd_prj <- terra::project(rsd, ref)  


Thank you so much Jeffrey! Small correction: sd() won't work. It is stdev().
Your suggestion about the CRS conversion also caught my attention. But when I try to reproject in this manner, the process seemed to take an exceptionally long time. Eventually, I interrupted the conversion, and R either crashed or displayed messages like:
Error: [project] interrupted
In addition: Warning message:[project] Estimated disk space needed without compression: 273620521GB. Available: 261 GB.
Given this, I'm wondering if it's even feasible to perform the conversion under these circumstances?

@Emma For the most part terra has tried to stick with standard functions calls (eg., min, max, median, ..) so, it surprises me that sd is, in fact, terra::stdev, fixed it in the answer. How big is your raster? I just finished reprojecting a 239532 x 356152 (n=85,309,800,864) single band and 7984 x 11872 with 374 bands (n=35,449,981,952) with no issues, just time (with 64GB RAM). If you do not have enough RAM to project the entire raster, you could implement a tiling scheme. That said, a 273,620 TB raster does not make much sense, even uncompressed so, there may be something else going on.

The dimension of standard deviation raster rsd is 2160*4320, and resolution is 0.08333333. However, the dimension of ref is 176213523 * 416820731, and resolution is also 0.08333333. Could this the be issue?

@Emma Yes, that is a huge problem, dimensions should approximately match. I would need to seen your code but, I image that if you are using the example verbatim it setting the resolution of the ref to  0.083 m. You need to set a sensible resolution for the reference raster that defines the new projection space eg., rast(e, resolution = 1000, crs= crs("ESRI:54017")) I believe that the approximate spatial resolution of 0.0833 degrees is 1000 m^2.

Thank you so much for your patience and help! I indeed used your code exactly as provided previously. Now may I ask how to estimate or calculate a suitable resolution for the conversion process? Is there a formula or method to do that? The dataset I'm working with, obtained from WorldClim, has a spatial resolution of 5 minutes, and its original CRS is EPSG:4326. Next time I may download datasets with different resolutions. Ultimately, my goal is to map these different data to my own grids, which are of equal area (hence my use of 'ESRI:54017' and each grid is 325 km² in size).

I am not clear on "mapping to my own grids". It does not matter if the data is vector or raster, spherical geometry over large scales will distort grid/cell size. Projections like Behrmann or Mollweide mitigate it somewhat but you will still have distortion. Once a raster is projected in to 54017, it would share the same properties as your grid. When you reproject a raster just define a cell size that matches your 325 km^2. It gets resampled no matter what. If one of my grad students proposed this it would give me pause.

To provide context, I've divided the Earth into grids using the 'ESRI:54017' CRS, as suggested here link. Within these grids, I've quantified species richness and am correlating it with climate variables. I rasterize the grids and use terra::zonal to compute the mean of each variable within each grid. My approach may involve unnecessary steps due to my novice understanding. I now realize that as long as the climate raster data cells outnumber my grids, any resolution will suffice.

Instead of getting a glimpse of your SpatRaster values via as_tibble(), it's far more convenient (at least from my point of view) to simply print your object. This will provide necessary insights into the most important spatial attributes associated (dims, res, extent, crs) but also a brief summary of your values (if available).
This back-and-forth conversion between objects from {raster} and {terra} is not necessary here and complicates your workflow but let's inspect your current output nevertheless:
temp_sd <- calc(stack(temp_list), fun = sd)
temp_sd
#> class      : RasterLayer 
#> dimensions : 2160, 4320, 9331200  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
#> resolution : 0.08333333, 0.08333333  (x, y)
#> extent     : -180, 180, -90, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#> crs        : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs 
#> source     : r_tmp_2024-05-05_212513.866903_20436_24080.grd 
#> names      : layer 
#> values     : 0, 23.73349  (min, max)

temp_sd_SpatRas <- as(temp_sd, "SpatRaster")
temp_sd_SpatRas
#> class       : SpatRaster 
#> dimensions  : 2160, 4320, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
#> resolution  : 0.08333333, 0.08333333  (x, y)
#> extent      : -180, 180, -90, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#> coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs 
#> source      : r_tmp_2024-05-05_212513.866903_20436_24080.grd 
#> name        :    layer 
#> min value   :  0.00000 
#> max value   : 23.73349

# convert to other CRS
envRasterESRI54017 <- project(temp_sd_SpatRas, "ESRI:54017")
envRasterESRI54017
#> class       : SpatRaster 
#> dimensions  : 1881, 4449, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
#> resolution  : 7806.161, 7803.765  (x, y)
#> extent      : -17367530, 17362081, -7336652, 7342230  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#> coord. ref. : World_Behrmann (ESRI:54017) 

Focussing on the values of temp_sd and temp_sd_SpatRas, you can see immediately that your conversion between the RasterLayer and SpatRaster object apparently worked, but envRasterESRI54017 simply seems to be missing values after project() since there is no summary given.
So the question is not why your layer is gone after projection but why the values of your SpatRaster are dropped after reprojection.
In fact, I can't really tell you why {terra} behaves like this but in the past I have experienced that there are some memory issues or the like from time to time when dealing with large raster and that it might be beneficial to dump your result to disk using the filename argument with overwrite = TRUE (actually, with filename only this still fails...) when noticing such an issue:
envRasterESRI54017 <- project(temp_sd_SpatRas, "ESRI:54017", filename = "envRasterESRI54017.tif", overwrite = TRUE)
envRasterESRI54017
#> class       : SpatRaster 
#> dimensions  : 1881, 4449, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
#> resolution  : 7806.161, 7803.765  (x, y)
#> extent      : -17367530, 17362081, -7336652, 7342230  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#> coord. ref. : World_Behrmann (ESRI:54017) 
#> source(s)   : envRasterESRI54017.tif 
#> name        :    layer 
#> min value   :  0.00000 
#> max value   : 23.63416

Et voila, there are your values.
PS: Still, when going for a common crs to combine raster and vector data for certain operations, I'd try not to alter original raster data by (bilinear) resampling as a result of reprojection. Instead, I'd reproject your vector Behrmann grid you created before to WGS84 ("EPSG:4326"), which should still be equal-area in "ESRI:54017", and leave your raster data in the original reference system. This should be sufficient to make terra::zonal() work and would also be much more efficient to process.

Thank you so much for the clarification!! I might misunderstand CRS before. Now I understand it as the area of polygons (grids) would remain (almost?) the same no matter what CRS is used? Grid01 under "ESRI:54017" is still Grid01 under "EPSG:4326". If so, I should convert grids to "EPSG:4326" and do analysis with this CRS since all other data (both vector and raster data) I downloaded are with "EPSG:4326".

Unfortunately, when I try to follow this approach (convert "ESRI:54017" grids to "EPSG:4326"), something went wrong... I have posted the issue in more detail here.

What you are describing with missing values after project can be attributed to trying to project a raster that is neither in-memory or on disk. I have run into this issue after mosaic/merge operations. In these cases, when you run project, it creates an empty object. You can deal with this by writing out a temp raster or, more generally by setting  terraOptions(todisk=TRUE) so that temp rasters are never held in memory (or think they are).

@Emma: Not quite, maybe check the QGIS docs regarding CRS or some other material on this topic. In my understanding, you choose a suitable projection with least distortions according to your needs. That's what you did by creating your equal-area grid in "ESRI:54017". You can best see what happens to your grid by e.g. overlaying this with a countries dataset, e.g. rnaturalearthdata::countries50. Try plotting two options, using "ESRI:54017" and "EPSG:4326" to get a feeling for distortions.

Key properties of your features, like the equal-area grid created in World_Behrmann (always referring to the original crs), should be preserved even after reprojection - although the grid will look quite distorted in WGS84 the further north/south you move from the equator. So Grid01 would be characterized by different geometries using different crs in the end and hence not be the same. But the equal area property originating from the use of "ESRI:54017" should still be preserved - if I'm not off the mark.
